# Why does drawRect: work without calling [super drawrect:rect]?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I'm overriding drawRect: in one of my views and it works even without calling [super drawrect:rect]. How does that work?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{  
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDestinationOver);
    [[UIColor clearColor] setFill];
    UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0,0,100,100));
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the documentation:

> "The default implementation of this method does nothing.Subclasses
>   that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their
>   view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing
>   code there"

Also from the documentation..

> "If you subclass UIView directly, your implementation of this method
>   does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a
>   different view class, you should call super at some point in your
>   implementation."

[Link to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawRect:)

I am assuming, your super class is UIView. Hence it works even if [super drawrect:rect] is not called. Because the drawRect: because UIView does nothing. So it makes no difference in this case whether or not you call [super drawrect:rect].

Answer (score 5):

Basically, it works because the machinery that sets up the graphics context for drawing, etc, doesn't live in the `UIView` implementation of `-drawRect:` (which is empty).

That machinery does live somewhere, of course, let's pretend in every UIView there's some internal method like this-- names of methods, functions, and properties are invented to protect the innocent:

```
- (void)_drawRectInternal:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Setup for drawing this view.
    _UIGraphicsContextPushTransform(self._computedTransform);

    // Call this object's implementation of draw (may be empty, or overridden).
    [self drawRect:rect];

    // draw our subviews: 
    for (UIView * subview in [self subviews]) {
        [subview _drawRectInternal:rect];
    }

    // Teardown for this view.
    _UIGraphicsContextPopTransform();
}
```

This is a cleaner way of building the frameworks than relying on a subclasser to do the right thing in a common override, where getting it wrong would have result in very puzzling bad behavior. (And this wouldn't really be possible at all since the draw might need a setup and a teardown step.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure subview doesn't work without calling [super drawrect:rect].If you need to keep the superview's drawing ,you must add [super drawrect:rect] in the subview's drawrect:rect,or you'll replace the drawing.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks.. There is no need to call super, because the superclass here is UIView, whose drawRect: does nothing.

In general, we call setNeedDisplay if we want recall drawRect for drawing.

Comment: This is incorrect explanation.. In general, when a sub class overrides a method of super class, it has to make a call to super. And secondly, just because drawRect is not called directly on a view, doesn't means super drawRect is not to be called..

Comment: Thanks.. There is no need to call super, because the superclass here is UIView, whose drawRect: does nothing.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=4MPks3aB_D8C&pg=PA422&lpg=PA422&dq=why+we+don't+call+super+drawrect&source=bl&ots=lXzshq7XDQ&sig=o2fDJJdTT_9buX_hL8zRaNr2nno&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NftFVIWRC9OgugTCqILwBw&ved=0CEEQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=why%20we%20don't%20call%20super%20drawrect&f=false