# How do I create a circle with CALayer?

Tags: swift, calayer

I have the code below tested, but when I give it constraints it becomes a little small circle:

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
var path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect)
fillColor.setFill()
path.fill()

//set up the width and height variables
//for the horizontal stroke
let plusHeight:CGFloat = 300.0
let plusWidth:CGFloat = 450.0

//create the path
var plusPath = UIBezierPath()

//set the path's line width to the height of the stroke
plusPath.lineWidth = plusHeight

//move the initial point of the path
//to the start of the horizontal stroke
plusPath.moveToPoint(CGPoint(
  x:self.bounds.width/2 - plusWidth/2 + 0.5,
  y:self.bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

//add a point to the path at the end of the stroke
plusPath.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(
  x:self.bounds.width/2 + plusWidth/2 + 0.5,
  y:self.bounds.height/2 + 0.5))

}
```

Comment: try putting it in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change radius and fillColor as you want. :)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CircleLayerView: UIView {
    var circleLayer: CAShapeLayer!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        if circleLayer == nil {
            circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
            let radius: CGFloat = 150.0
            circleLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 2.0 * radius, height: 2.0 * radius), cornerRadius: radius).cgPath
            circleLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - radius, y: self.frame.midY - radius)
            circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            self.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nitpicky but there's no need to call super here since you're subclassing UIView: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26479578/3128245

Comment: Also, to avoid making circleLayer an implicitly unwrapped optional (`CAShapeLayer!`), you could instantiate `let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()` and guard against it having a superlayer with `guard circleLayer.superlayer == nil else { return }` in drawRect

Comment: I forget which WWDC session it was, but Apple said you shouldn't be adding layers in drawRect. Which makes sense. Instead, set up your layers after the view's layout has been done, configure them, then leave the rendering system to handle them automatically

Comment: This answer is : completely wrong.

Answer (score 15):

The `rect` being passed into `drawRect` is the area that needs to be updated, not the size of the drawing. In your case, you would probably just ignore the rect being passed in and set the circle to the size you want.

```
    //// Oval Drawing
    var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300))
    UIColor.whiteColor().setFill()
    ovalPath.fill()
```

Comment: This Should be the accepted Answer. `ovalInRect` is the correct way. Others are just workarounds

Answer (score 0):

### The only correct way to do it:

```
private lazy var whiteCoin: CAShapeLayer = {
    let c = CAShapeLayer()
    c.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    c.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.addSublayer(c)
    return c
}()
```

That literally **makes a layer**, as you wanted.

In iOS you must correctly resize any layers you are in charge of, when the view is resized/redrawn.

How do you do that? It is the very raison d'etre of `layoutSubviews`.

```
class ProperExample: UIView {
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        whiteCoin.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

It's that simple.

```
class ProperExample: UIView {
    open override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        whiteCoin.frame = bounds
    }
    private lazy var whiteCoin: CAShapeLayer = {
        let c = CAShapeLayer()
        c.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
        c.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(c)
        return c
    }()
}
```