# What unit does Swift use for angles?

Tags: swift, uiview, drawrect, angle, units-of-measurement

Am am writing some code to draw circular charts, and while reading some example code, became confused about how angles are measured in Swift.

In the [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30556058/6496271) I read, Swift seems to use radians:

```
CGContextAddArc(context, origo.x, origo.y, radius, floatPi * 3 / 2, floatPi * 3 / 2 + floatPi * 2 * percent, 0)
```

In the [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31812742/6496271), Swift seems to define angles as a range from 0 to 1:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 150, height: 150))
var segments: [CAShapeLayer] = []
let segmentAngle: CGFloat = (360 * 0.125) / 360

for var i = 0; i < 8; i++ {
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    circleLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath

    // start angle is number of segments * the segment angle
    circleLayer.strokeStart = segmentAngle * CGFloat(i)

    // end angle is the start plus one segment, minus a little to make a gap
    // you'll have to play with this value to get it to look right at the size you need
    let gapSize: CGFloat = 0.008
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = circleLayer.strokeStart + segmentAngle - gapSize

    circleLayer.lineWidth = 10
    circleLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0,  green:0.004,  blue:0.549, alpha:1).CGColor
    circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    // add the segment to the segments array and to the view
    segments.insert(circleLayer, atIndex: i)
    view.layer.addSublayer(segments[i])
}
```

So, how does Swift measure angles?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift has absolutely nothing to do with the angle unit, it's just a `Float`/`Double` to it. It's the functions of the Core Graphics framework that specify what angle unit they're expecting. Just read the docs of the functions in question.

From the [CGContextAddArc docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextAddArc):

> startAngle: The angle to the starting point of the arc, measured in radians from the positive x-axis.
>
> endAngle: The angle to the end point of the arc, measured in radians from the positive x-axis.

Also the `strokeStart` and `strokeEnd` properties of the `CAShapeLayer` say what part of the given path should be drawn, it's not an angle. Just read [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CAShapeLayer/strokeStart) next time.